# Where does IIS Express get its default applicationhost.config from?

Tags: visual-studio-code, iis-express

I added a couple of MIME types to the `applicationhost.config` files in `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer` and `C:\Users\<me>\Documents\IISExpress\config\`. But every time I launch IIS Express, it creates a new file in `/Temp/IISExpress/` that doesn't have those MIME types.

Where is it getting that new file from?

FYI: I'm launching IIS Express via [this VSCode plugin](https://github.com/warrenbuckley/IIS-Express-Code)

Comment: This is specific to the extension, so either you ask it's developer or check its source code.

Comment: If IISExpress is run without specifying a config file, it makes a copy of the one in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer`. It has nothing to do with the extension.

Comment: Note if you run another tool (like VS), it won't use this file at all. That's why I said you hit a specific case. Anyway, VS has a much larger user base than VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. There's another config file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\AppServer`